# How to perform android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG while developing in cordova

Tags: android, cordova

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/support/index.html#core-plugin-apis

I don't see any `cordova` core plugins that allow you to read phone logs. But Android allows you to do it [with].

```
android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across one cordova plugin for reading call logs in Android. This [Call-Log plugin](https://github.com/dalyc/Cordova-CallLog-Plugin) should help you get started. Hope it helps